# Eclipse does not start after Linux Update

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I am using Eclipse adjusted for TCL language installed on Ubuntu Studio, 
after update of the system I am trying to launch Eclipse, but it does not start. It shows error message " An error has occurred. See the log file ... ". When I see the log file the message is:

```
!SESSION Mon Sep 17 11:54:53 EEST 2018 -----------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2018-09-17 11:54:53.982
!STACK

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter

at
java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)

    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

I understand that maybe java is the problem, but I am not sure what to do.

```
Eclipse: eclipse 3.8.1-11

openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
```

The eclipse.ini file says:

> -configuration ../../../home/myHomeFolder/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Update: I also tryed to reinstall Eclipse, Java and Ubuntu after all with the original desktop Ubuntu distro (not Ubuntu Studio) and still have the same issue after trying to start Eclipse. The log file is complete and this is the whole message displayed.

=================== LAST UPDATE ======================

What it seemed to be the problem was the Java indeed. 
After the update the newest Java version was installed and the Eclipse was searching for the old one. Because I couldn't launch the application at all I have installed the newest version Eclipse Photon, now it starts well.

Comment: why even bother posting here, just throw away old eclipse and reinstall it from scratch?

Comment: The log message seems to be incomplete. Please show the complete message and the content of the `eclipse.ini` file.

Comment: Gathering the versions of Java and Eclipse involved would be the first thing to do.

Comment: I edited the post with the things I tryed to do.

Comment: Please don't add things like "solved" to the title of your question. If you managed to solve your problem, consider posting an answer with a complete solution, and accept that after the timeout.